# What is wrong with com port comminucation if I get CE_FRAME errors?

Tags: c++, windows, serial-port

I am trying to understand why I get CE_FRAME error in a serial communication. The documentation reads:

> The hardware detected a framing error. Returned when the SERIAL_LSR_FE bit is detected in the LSR hardware register.
>
> This is the framing error indicator. It is set whenever the hardware detects that the incoming serial data unit does not have a valid stop bit. This bit is cleared by reading this register:
>
> define SERIAL_LSR_FE 0x08

But I don't really know what shall I do with this *valid stop bit*. Can I just ignore this?

I have no other issues with the communication. Every packet of data (send by the device) is being captured on the PC. On the PC I am using `ClearCommError()` to detect statistics of the channel, and from time to time I got this CE_FRAME flag on.
I am not sure if I have to provide details about the `CreateFile()` and `SetCommState()` function calls in my code, as there are nothing 'special' about them. But if needed, I can.

Comment: No, this is an ugly problem that you cannot ignore, it is a telltale sign of low-level data corruption.  Maybe it doesn't corrupt the data bytes, but you can never be sure that it won't on a rainy day.  You need to get ahead by at least lowering the baudrate and verifying that you won't get them anymore.  If that doesn't fix it then you have an electrical noise problem.

Comment: Thank Hans. I will accept your reply as answer, if you post it as answer :).

Answer (score 1):

If you are programming on Windows then the application programmer does not set start and stop bits, the 'system' takes care of applying the start/stop bits as well as possible parity bits, baud rate and even some other settings.  The critical ones are baud rate, start and stop bits and parity bits.

The system being the hardware or operating system.  I think it is the UART chip which adds the start and stop bits.  But you need to set the actual configuration to use in software.

What you do have to do is set the start and stop bits the same on both ends.  So if you are communicating with a device which uses 1 start bit and 2 stop bits, then you have to set this same setting for your communication end.

You are likely to get framing errors if these settings are NOT set the same on both ends of the communication.  I have seen framing errors where for example I set the baud rate 1200 one end but 9600 the other end.  Actually my start and stop bits were correctly set both ends.  So it may well be something simple like that.